# how to add fancybox to website using visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I'm having an issue creating a fancybox in my website while using visual studio 2012.  How will I add them together what is the best to make it work.

Comment: What type of VS Project is it? WebForms, MVC, Website...? Also, what have you done so far to integrate or create the fancybox?

Answer (score 1):

I've just added it to my own project, try this:

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console

In the console type:

Install-Package Fancybox

If you're using MVC you can add this to the bundle config:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fancybox").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-media.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel-*"));
```

and add these to your css bundle:

```
                  "~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"
```

Fancybox can then be instantiate as per the documentation:

<a id="single_image" href="#"><img src="" /></a>

$("a#single_image").fancybox();